# Inheritance Mapping

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa

i have to do a webapplication with JPA and i have some questions about the design of the database and the mapping with hibernate.

I did a simple example to explain my problem, we have the entity book inherit from the entity item, we can have others classes wich inherit from the item Class.and we have the class order_line how hase an relation with the item class, we have foreign key in the order_line Class

my 2 clases would by like that:

```
@Entity
public class Book extends item implements Serializable{
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private String isbn;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private String language;
}
```

and the Super class :

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class item implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private String title;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private Integer price;
}
```

and for the third Class order_line:

```
@Entity
public class order_line implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer quantity;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "item_fk", nullable = false)
    private Item item;
  }
```

with this simple code we are shure thate we have fk in the Order_line table.but the problem is that this foreign key is for the item table or the book table.
because i did example in the database and i had One item with id=1 and One Book whith Id=1.

how to manage this hierarchy.and please help me, thank you very much

Comment: you shouldn't have an entry in the item table, maybe the error lies in the code where you create / persist the entities.

Comment: btw, you should name classes with a capital starting letter: "Item" not "item" and "OrderLine" instead of "order_line". That's just the way we do it in java.